# Firebase Remote config (angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

i am trying to use `Firebase Remote Config`. For the other services they provide there is a wrapper:

[angularfire](https://github.com/angular/angularfire)

However i can seem to see that `Remote config` is supported?

So following the [documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-config) i have made the following `service`:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {FirebaseConfig} from '@ionic-native/firebase-config/ngx';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TextService {

    constructor(private firebaseConfig: FirebaseConfig) {
        this.firebaseConfig.getString('language_da').then((result) => {
            console.log(result);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

However this gives me an `inject` error:

```
  core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[FirebaseConfig]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[FirebaseConfig]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for FirebaseConfig!
```

Can anyone tell me the correct way of using `Remote config` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your import is not correct:

```
import { FirebaseConfig } from '@ionic-native/firebase-config';


constructor(private firebaseConfig: FirebaseConfig) { }
```

And just to be sure Install the Cordova and Ionic Native plugins:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-config
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/firebase-config@4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however if i look at the documentation my import should be correct?